# Changing params for search with rails and sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

This seems like a common task, I'm sure others have come across it.

**If my controller says this :**

```
def index
  s = Sunspot.search Organization do |query|
    query.keywords params[:q] unless params[:q].blank?
    query.with(:searchable).equal_to(params[:filter_by] == 'published' ? 'true' : false) if params[:filter_by]
  ..
```

**How do I:**

.. through a link, make it change its `query.with(:searchable)` statement to `query.with(:has_no_deals)` ?

Here's my starter link that doesn't work, because the old `query.with(:searchable)` is not overwritten:

```
= link_to 'Has No Deals', url_for(:overwrite_params => { :filter_by => 'dfgsdgsdf', :page => nil })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this little baby in your controller

```
query.with(:searchable).equal_to(params[:filter_by] == 'published' ? 'true' : false) if params[:filter_by] == ( 'published' || 'unpublished' )

query.with(:has_no_deals).equal_to(params[:filter_by] == 'has_no_deals' ? 'true' : false) if params[:filter_by] == 'has_no_deals'
```